# Can I test on the order of elements using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

There is a form in which there are 3 fields with 3 different ID's:

```
<fieldset>
<div><label for="field1">
 FIELD1
 </label>
 <textarea id="field1" name="field1" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></div>


 <div><label for="field2">
  FIELD2
</label><textarea id="field2" name="field2" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></div>


<div><label for="field3">
  FIELD3
</label><textarea id="field3" name="field3" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></div>

</fieldset>
```

Now, there is a Story in our scrum process which places FIELD3 at the top of the page, above FIELD1, so that the new order of fields will be 3, 1, 2.

My question is: Is there a way to verify/assert the order? If yes, how do I test this automatically using Selenium Webdriver (java)?

Comment: can you share the parent of these "`<div>`"'s please?

Comment: Order within the DOM and order shown to the user on screen, **can** be different. (Just to throw a spanner into the works ;))

Comment: @sircapsalot: I recon you mean the tags that tie all the <divs> together? I edited my first post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You sure can.  Here's some pseudo-code.

```
assertTrue(
    driver.findElement(
        By.cssSelector("div#parent > div:nth-child(1) > textarea#field3")
    ).isDisplayed()
);
```

The logic here pretty much says:

> Look for the first `div` that is under `<div id="parent">`, that is immediately followed by `<textarea id="field3">`.   If this assertion fails, that means it's out of order, and the third field is NOT first.

*(note, that div#parent is obviously subject to change.  You need to change it to the parent of these divs, and you may also need to fiddle about with the `:nth-child(n)` depending on the order)*

Comment: So, Before the assertTrue, I should have a piece of code to determine the Parnent-Element? Someting like parent = (driver.findelement(By.Id("text")?

Comment: with CSS, you don't need to do anything with the parent element.  In the case that I gave you, `"div#parent > div:nth-child(1)"` the `div#parent` is BEFORE the `div:nth-child(1)` therefore meaning "a parent of"

Answer (score 0):

```
public String ValidateOrderOfResRentFilters(ExtentTest test) throws InterruptedException {
String xpath_FilterOrder="//div[@id='abcd']";

List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath_FilterOrder));
List<String> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    
for(WebElement e: element){
      String str = e.getText();
      System.out.println("The items are  " + str);
      filters.add(str);
    }
    System.out.println(ret);
    return filters.toString();
}
```