# Is there any way to test display order sequence of web elements in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, coordinates, sequence

**Problem Statement:** I have web page with 4 carousels (say A, B, C, D). I need to verify their correct display order on the UI (and not in HTML code).
Few points to test:

1. A should be on top always and will be displayed every time.
2. B, C D should follow order : A > B > C > D   (Making A appear always on top and D always last or on bottom)
3. The order should be as above even if any of the carousels are not displayed. (Like if C is not displayed the order should be A > B > D).
4. Any one/two/all of B, C, D may not be displayed on page.

Test should be able to identify the sequence on both desktop and mobile browsers.

**Solution I tried:**
Find all the elements and get their Y coordinates using **getLocation().getY()** in Selenium. Compare the Y coordinates and identify which one is at top.

**Current issue:**
The above solution only works for Desktop browsers, and not for mobile browsers like chrome for iOS or Android, as getLocation() always returns (0,0) for all web elements.

**Similar question:** Its not much related with my issue:
[Can I test on the order of elements using Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133024/can-i-test-on-the-order-of-elements-using-selenium-webdriver)

**Other Details:**
- I'm using **Java 1.8** with **Selenium 2.53**
- All tests are executing on Browser Stack

**How do I achieve this using Selenium Web Driver and JAVA?**

Comment: How about posting some code? :) And ideally the URL of the webpage you're testing, if possible.

Comment: It's an internal website, still you can try the same on the amazon.com which has multiple sections on home page which keep changing the order.